# Retrieve Intent's String data in CustomAdapter

Tags: java, android

I have a MainActivity and I navigate to second activity after Login.In main activity I have username and password.

```
Intent mainintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,FirstPage.class);
mainintent.putExtra("username",etemail.getText().toString());
mainintent.putExtra("password",etpass.getText().toString());
                                    startActivity(mainintent);
```

I want that username and password in customAdapter.class which handles cardview.
When I use it as

```
String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
String password = getIntent().getStringExtra("password");
```

I get cannot resolve method getIntent().
How can I get the username and password in this class.

This calss extends `RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>` and not Activity.
Thanks

Comment: you have to first get user/pass in activity and then pass as parameter to adapter class constructor

Comment: can you show it please??do you mean using getters/setters?

Comment: no. first get data using String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
String password = getIntent().getStringExtra("password");   and , when you set adapter. add additional two parameter. and access that from adapter

Comment: you have to use the context at custom adapter to use the getIntent() method... better use shared preference to store the user details as it will become easier to handle and you can use it over and again....

Comment: Better to Use SharedPreference and store both username and password and get that in any activity or class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In constructor of custom adapter you could store a reference to activity. 
Then you could use that reference to get the intent.

```
public CustomAdapter(Activity activity,..){
  mActivity = activity;
}
```

Comment: While declaring the adapter in the class how can I declare it?

Comment: adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.class,this,data_list);

Comment: if you instantiate the adapter from activity then you could use new CustomAdapter(this, data_list); If you instantiate it from an inner class then you could use new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, data_list);

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the username,password to constructer,

```
SimpleAdapter myAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, myArrayList , username, password);
```

and use those into your adapter.